# Google Ads API - How to fetch data with MCC (manager account)

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I am trying to fetch campaigns' reports from Google Ads API.
But, getting an error when trying to fetch data with MCC:

**Code:**

```
  import sys,os
  from google.ads.google_ads.client import GoogleAdsClient
  from google.ads.google_ads.errors import GoogleAdsException

  def get_data(client, customer_id):
    ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService", version="v6")

    query = """
        SELECT
          campaign.name,
          campaign.status,
          segments.device,
          metrics.impressions,
          metrics.clicks,
          metrics.ctr,
          metrics.average_cpc,
          metrics.cost_micros
        FROM campaign
        WHERE segments.date DURING LAST_30_DAYS
        """

    # Issues a search request using streaming.
    response = ga_service.search_stream(customer_id, query=query)

    try:
        for batch in response:
            for row in batch.results:
                print(
                    row
                )
    except GoogleAdsException as ex:
        print(
            f'Request with ID "{ex.request_id}" failed with status '
            f'"{ex.error.code().name}" and includes the following errors:'
        )
        for error in ex.failure.errors:
            print(f'\tError with message "{error.message}".')
            if error.location:
                for field_path_element in error.location.field_path_elements:
                    print(f"\t\tOn field: {field_path_element.field_name}")
        sys.exit(1)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        # get client object with oauth2
        credentials = {'developer_token': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            'refresh_token': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            'client_id': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            'client_secret': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                       }
        google_ads_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_dict(credentials)
    
        get_data(google_ads_client, 'xxxxxxxxx')
```

**Wehn Running the code with MCC client ID:**

```
get_data(google_ads_client, 'MANAGER(MCC)_CLIENT_ID')
```

**I'm Getting Error_1:**

Request made: ClientCustomerId: xxxxxxxxx, Host: googleads.googleapis.com:443, Method: /google.ads.googleads.v6.services.GoogleAdsService/SearchStream, RequestId: xxxxxxxxxx, IsFault: True, FaultMessage: Metrics cannot be requested for a manager account. To retrieve metrics, issue separate requests against each client account under the manager account.

I assumed, the solution would be to set **a different ClientCustomerId** of the account itself, not MCC.
So I did, and run the code again with the client id of the direct account, and, got another error:

**Wehn Running the code with Account client ID:**

```
get_data(google_ads_client, 'ACCOUNT_CLIENT_ID')
```

**I'm Getting Error_2:**

Request made: ClientCustomerId: xxxxxxx, Host: googleads.googleapis.com:443, Method: /google.ads.googleads.v6.services.GoogleAdsService/SearchStream, RequestId: xxxxxxxxxx, IsFault: True, FaultMessage: User doesn't have permission to access customer. Note: If you're accessing a client customer, the manager's customer id must be set in the 'login-customer-id' header. See https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/concepts/call-structure#cid

That error essentially says to insert the manager's client id, which I already did and got error_1 (!).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved:**

The function should be initiated with **account client id**:

```
get_data(google_ads_client, 'ACCOUNT_CLIENT_ID')
```

AND, a key-value pair should be added to the credentials dict (the MCC client id):

```
    credentials = {'developer_token': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        'refresh_token': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        'client_id': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        'client_secret': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        // Add this line below
        'login_customer_id': 'mcc_client_id'
                   }
```

Comment: Hi, i am having the same problem.
Did you use the id from the account, or the id from the manager account?
And the refresh token, did you use the one you got from the OAuth login?

Comment: Hi, care to explain, where you got the account_client_id and mcc_client_id? did those two are the customer id you mean? if not, where I can find the id? Thanks!

Comment: @filipe I used the id of the Account when calling the "get_data" function. But you also need to add the MCC id to the credentials dict (you can see it in the example I wrote).

Comment: @uzrsa account_client_id should be taken from your Google Ads Account, simply look there for its id. Same the goes for the MCC id, you need to look for it in your Google Ads Account.

Comment: @IdoS thanks a lot, it enlighten me so much!